# Get WSDL URL or data of google analytics

Tags: web-services, google-analytics, wsdl, google-analytics-api

I want to get WSDL URL of google analytics.
I search on net but it is all about embedd API.

1) Is it possible to get WSDL URL of my Google analytics dashboard?
OR
2)Fetch data of google analytics into any RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is SOAP. [Google Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) is REST. Embed API is a Javascript API client (which is based on the REST API).

So 1) there is no WSDL for GA, but 2) you do not need it. The linked documentation has examples, and Google offers API client libraries for different programming languages (and the API itself is language agnostic).

Comment: Hi, Eike, I am not using any programming language, Hence I guess I can not use API.My purpose is to fetch the data in my dashboard. Another way is possible if anyhow I can get it in Relational database, like SQL SERVER.

Comment: If you do not want to do any programming you'll have to use one of the commercial services that allow you to embed reports directly. GA does not have any widget (that I am aware of) that would allow you to embed reports without programming (the closes ist possibly the Google Spreadsheet add-on if you publish the sheet with the results to the web).